# How to add a sidebar widget before layered navigation filter in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

Widgets assigned to sidebar (from admin) appears after filter, any way to push it upwards ?

Answer (score -1):

It might be added in **Sidebar Additional**. so you will have to move the side bar additional before the **Sidebar Main**.
Add this line in your xml file.

```
 <move element="div.sidebar.additional" destination="columns" before="div.sidebar.main" />
```